# Get ID from Form:select inside if-else in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have 2 `Form::select's` inside an `id-else` statement in my view in **Laravel 5.5**. How do I get the id from these? Tried to put the ID in there on several location but none works..

this is part of the view:

```
<div class="o-grid__col u-12/12@sm">
    {!! Form::label('', __('profile.contactSalutation').'*') !!}
    @if( Session::get('urlLang') == "en" )
        {!! Form::select(__('contact_contactSalutation'), array('Miss' => 'Miss', 'Sir' => 'Sir'),array('class' => 'c-dropdown c-dropdown__simple u-mb-x6'),['required' => 'required']) !!}
    @else
        {!! Form::select(__('contact_contactSalutation'), array('Frau' => 'Frau', 'Herr' => 'Herr'),array('class' => 'c-dropdown c-dropdown__simple u-mb-x6'),['required' => 'required']) !!}
    @endif
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the definition of `Form::select`:

```
{!! Form::select(NAME, OPTIONS, DEFAULT_SELECTED, ['id' => 'test', 'class' => 'any-class', ... so on with the extras in this array]) !!}
```

in your case will be:

```
{!! Form::select(__('contact_contactSalutation'), array('Miss' => 'Miss', 'Sir' => 'Sir'), null, array('id' => 'YOUR ID HERE', 'class' => 'c-dropdown c-dropdown__simple u-mb-x6', 'required' => 'required')) !!}
```

notice the `null` (so nothing pre-selected) as the third argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$choices = ['Frau'=> 'Frau', 'Herr'=> 'Herr'];

{!! Form::select(__('contact_contactSalutation'), $choices, null, ['id' => 'my_id', 'class'=> 'c-dropdown c-dropdown__simple u-mb-x6', 'required']) !!}

or //if you want to select a default value

{!! Form::select(__('contact_contactSalutation'), $choices, $result->contact ?? null, ['id' => 'my_id', 'class'=> 'c-dropdown c-dropdown__simple u-mb-x6', 'required']) !!}
```

`$result->contact` is your DB column name

3rd argument is used for a selected value you can use coalesce Operator either from a saved value or null